# Example of hiding mechanism in Squeak, similar to C++

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the [Hiding mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#Language-specific_examples) in Squeak, similar to the one in languages like C++ and C#, where its one of the main features. I know that I can override methods in Squeak and that I can't overload methods because its a dynamic languages, but Is it possible to hide methods/fields? I tried to dig in the Squeak logs but I could not find the answer. If it is possible to achieve hiding in Squeak I would be glad to see an example. If it's possible, what could be the reason? Maybe some OOP value which prohibits it?

Comment: While there is no explicit syntax that prohibits a call to super, if you don't call super from a method override, then the inherited implementation is effectively hidden. And, no, you can't prevent a subclass from having access to the superclass instance variables.

Comment: @JamesFoster your comment is actually an answer. Please promote it.

Answer (score 6):

While there is no explicit syntax that prohibits a call to super, if you don't call super from a method override, then the inherited implementation is effectively hidden. And, no, you can't prevent a subclass from having access to the superclass instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please read first @JamesFoster's answer.

It should be relatively easy to add support for disallowing `super`. As `super` is not always valid, or at least it shouldn't be when the superclass is `nil` (e.g., `ProtoObject`), the compiler should somewhere check for this condition before allowing `super` as a valid pseudo variable. Then it would be a matter of tweaking that check by asking the class whether it supports `super` or not (rather than whether its superclass is `nil`).

I've tried in Pharo and there is no check at all (meaning that you can send to `super` in `ProtoObject`). So, modifying the Pharo compiler could be a little harder.